# Why is one ASP.NET project referencing the NuGets while the other is referencing MS Build extensions?

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild, nuget, nodatime

Trying to update a project, we're getting `Assembly 'x.Core' with identity 'x.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Net.Http' with identity 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`

[image: Services vs UI]

```
services csproj

    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.4\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>

ui csproj

    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.4\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Currently builds before updating Core with a new version of NodaTime, after updating Core the error listed above is output during the build for the Services project. We've tried many workarounds, like uninstalling and reinstalling System.Net.Http, or installing other seemingly unrelated System.* NuGets. Trying to move from NodaTime 1.3.1 to 3.0.10. Projects are .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Could I suggest at least as an intermediate step (and for more information) updating to NodaTime 2.4.18? It's very strange though - NodaTime doesn't depend on System.Net.Http at all...

Comment: I'd also try updating your services project to use 4.2.0.0, the same as your UI project. (See the reference properties.)